# Meet my parents. This is / These are my mom and dad

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Correct please the phrases and explain please grammar:

1. Meet my parents. This is / These are my mom and dad.
   (plural after "this is" in new sentence)
2. My work is hard. It's swimming, running, shooting and jumping every day. (plural after "it's" in new sentence)

thanks a lot

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The correct sentence is:

**This is** my mom and dad.

The reasoning behind that is you are saying "**This is** my mom and **this is** my dad", not "**These people are both** my mom and dad."

The second sentence is syntactically correct, but is semantically wrong. It is weird to say that your work **is** "swimming, running, shooting and jumping every day" (since those are actions rather than "work"), but you should rather say:

My work is hard. It **consists** of swimming, running, shooting and jumping every day.

A less harsh alternative that you can use in verbal communication is:

My work is hard. **I have to** swim, run, shoot and jump every day.

Answer (score -1):

This is my mom and (this is) my dad.

In parallel constructions, repeated words may be omitted.

See also [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/269118/could-a-sentence-like-this-one-below-be-proper/269119#269119)