# Could a sentence like this one below be proper?

Tags: grammar

Could a sentence like this one below be proper?

> "She was sleeping or in some other state of repose."

'Was' forms the past continuous tense in this case, can it still work as a normal verb - to be - in the following part of a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It is proper.  It is an example of a parallel construction.

> She was sleeping or (she was) in some other state of repose.

The repeated words can be omitted, even though "was" is an auxiliary verb in the first, and a main verb in the second clause.

However you are permitted to repeat the words for clarity, and many speakers would do so.

More doubtful would be

> She has rested and a big smile.  (??)

Strict parallelism would allow this to mean "She has rested and she has big smile" I don't think any native speaker would say this.

Comment: I think perhaps "has" in the sense of making a perfect tense and "has" in the sense of possessing something are two different meanings of "has", and you can't really do the parallel thing (except, perhaps, as a little joke) unless the words are not only the same word but the same meaning.